# Is there an open-source solution to XA-transactional file access in Java?

Tags: java, file, transactions, filesystems, jta

Is it possible to make XA-transactional access to the file system in Java? 
I want to manipulate files within the boundaries of a transaction and my transaction must participate in a distributed transaction via JTA (so I guess the file system needs to be accesses as a XAResource). I don't need support for fine-grained read/write file access; treating each file as a record is good enough for my needs.

Does anybody know an open-source project that already does this? I don't feel like implementing this mess just to find out that it's already been done...

I heard some rumors that JBoss Transcations will add support for this (see for example [this discussion](http://jboss.org/community/wiki/TransactionalFileIO)) but couldn't find an official statement about this.

By the way, if you need transactional file access but don't require the transaction to participate in a 2-phase commit I recommend you have a look at [Apache Commons Transaction](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/file/index.html)

A nice article about the complexities involved can be found in [here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/37798).

Comment: I done some searching on this recently and the only thing I came across was the JBoss code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I solved exactly the same problem. Finally I used [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home) with XADisk.

You can find more details in my blog post: [JTA transaction manager – Atomikos or Bitronix?](http://blog.trixi.cz/2011/11/jta-transaction-manager-atomikos-or-bitronix/)

Answer (score 6):

[XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) can get you what you are looking for. It's free and open source.

Answer (score 3):

At the time the JBoss Transactions intern started there was no XA capable file system driver for Java. I've not checked more recently, but nor have I seen any news about similar work. The work that Ioannis did during his internship is available if you want to use it, but not under active development at present. Unless you want to become an open source contributor :-)

At some point in the future when we have the time and/or customer demand we may roll this functionality into the product. Meanwhile it's at [www.jboss.org/jbosstm/fileio/](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/fileio/) and the original project discussion is at [www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossTSProjects](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossTSProjects)

Jonathan Halliday

JBossTS dev team

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! 

I'll get the JBossTM code and will give it a try... 
From what I've found, this seems like the best (open) effort done so far. Strange, I would think many people needed this functionality.

Thanks again,
Ori

Answer (score 0):

At Atomikos we did this about 10 years ago but dropped the idea due to lack of demand.

We could resume our efforts if there is sufficient reason to do so.