# Atomikos or JBossTS without JDBC

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, atomikos

is it possible to implement one of the former Transaction Manager if the datasource is not callable via JDBC?

**Edited**

I want to create an addin for an existing application. My addin shall be responsible for logging of the read and write accesses of long run workflow transactions. My addin should be additionally responsible for caching variables in case that they are required - so that there should not neccessarily be a read/write operation everytime a variable is accessed.

The application is running in a Tomcat6 environment and I get the data by calling a plugin manager ( which holds gets data from the different datasources ).

Do you know any links which I could read - or maybe know of some existing solution?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you still have not fully grasped the distinction between transaction manager and resource manager.  Transactions managers like JBossTS drive resource managers like Oracle, MSSQL etc, via XAResources supplied by the RM's drivers.

You're not implementing a transaction manager - it's already implemented. You're implementing a new resource manager and using the existing transaction manager to drive it. Read the XA specification, then implement XAResource and enlist your resource with the transaction manager. As long as your impl is spec compliant the transaction manager will use it just the same way it does with the implementations supplied by database drivers or message queues.

Note that doing I/O to external (i.e. non-transactional) systems in ACID transaction scope is basically impossible. The best you can hope for is some form of compensation based model or 1PC behaviour with last resource commit optimization.

Comment: True, but the connection to the data - the read and write operations on the different data sources ( files, databases ) is not in my scope of work, that is the work of a plugin manager. Mine is it to see if I need to update the (cached) variable - and do that ( and the read/write ) in a transactional manner.

Comment: Files are not naturally transactional. To read or write them in a transaction you'll need something like xadisk or JBoss transactional files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892349/is-there-an-open-source-solution-to-xa-transactional-file-access-in-java)

Comment: RAM is not transactional either, STM solutions aside. So, you need some transactional cache to hold the variable. Try infinispan maybe - it's a cache / datagrid that can act as an XA resource manager.